# How to parse Esri geometry coordinates that look like relative values?

Tags: arcgis-server, srid

While doing GIS system integration I encountered a kind of response data that I have no experience with. The coordinates looked very strange, except for the first one, the rest were mostly `[1, 1]`, `[1, 0]`, `[-1, 1]` or such. Is it some kind of relative values? How should I parse or convert them and eventually get the full absolute coordinate values?

The system was ArcGIS Server, and the response came from an API endpoint similar to `https://<host-hidden>/arcgis/rest/services/<data-name-hidden>/MapServer/dynamicLayer/query`. The request data was:

```
f:json

returnGeometry:true

spatialRel:esriSpatialRelIntersects

geometry:{"xmin":13045108.007364817,"ymin":-60420.400090846495,"xmax":13045337.318449672,"ymax":-60191.08900599128,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}}

geometryType:esriGeometryEnvelope

inSR:102100

outSR:102100

quantizationParameters:{"mode":"view","originPosition":"upperLeft","tolerance":19,"extent":{"xmin":94.97199999930154,"ymin":-11.007615088964371,"xmax":141.01999999940153,"ymax":6.07694033193161,"spatialReference":{"wkid":4326,"latestWkid":4326,"vcsWkid":115700,"latestVcsWkid":115700}}}

layer:{"source":{"type":"mapLayer","mapLayerId":3}}
```

And the response data looked like this (please notice the `features -> geometry -> rings` part):

```
{
    "displayFieldName": "giskemendagri.gisadmin.<hidden>.<hidden>",
    "transform": {
        "originPosition": "upperLeft",
        "scale": [
            19,
            19
        ],
        "translate": [
            94.971999999301545,
            6.0769403319316098
        ]
    },
    "fieldAliases": {
        "giskemendagri.gisadmin.<hidden>.<hidden>": "<hidden>"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100,
        "latestWkid": 3857
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "giskemendagri.gisadmin.<hidden>.<hidden>",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
            "alias": "<hidden>",
            "length": 10
        }
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "giskemendagri.gisadmin.<hidden>.<hidden>": "<hidden>"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "rings": [
                    [
                        [
                            686779,
                            3084
                        ],
                        [
                            4,
                            69
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            82
                        ],
                        [
                            -5,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -8,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            14
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            3
                        ],
                        [
                            3,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            6,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            7
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            9
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            4
                        ],
                        [
                            9,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            5,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            5,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            3,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            3,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            3,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            6,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            5,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            5,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            6,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            6,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            7,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            3,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            7,
                            4
                        ],
                        [
                            4,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            4,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            5,
                            3
                        ],
                        [
                            4,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            3,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            2,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            5
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            3
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            2,
                            4
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            3
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            3
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            3
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            10
                        ],
                        [
                            3,
                            7
                        ],
                        [
                            1,
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            3,
                            3
                        ],
                        [
                            6,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            -21,
                            12
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -5,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -3,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            0,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -2,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -3,
                            -2
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            -1
                        ],
                        [
                            -1,
                            0
                        ],
                        ...(cropped due to question length limitation)
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are relative values.  It's part of coordinate quantization to make the queries as small as possible (and thus faster), as well as the clientside parsing and implementation faster and better in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.  You can read more about coordinate quantization at https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-feature-service-layer-.htm and https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-support-Query.html#quantizationParameters

No, you probably shouldn't parse them. Instead change the query to return the coordinates in the format you want. It might be as simple as removing the `quantizationParameters` property in the REST request.